# Why does string not exist?

Tags: c

```
/*
    Hello World example made by Aurelio Mannara for libctru
    This code was modified for the last time on: 12/12/2014 21:00 UTC+1
*/

#include <3ds.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gfxInitDefault();

    char player[1024] = "\x1b[";
    int tesx = 1;
    char tesxx = tesx + '0';
    char ot[] = ";";
    char oty[] = "H0";
    int test = 3;
    char testt = test + '0';
    //Initialize console on top screen. Using NULL as the second argument tells the console library to use the internal console structure as current one
    consoleInit(GFX_TOP, NULL);
    strcat(player, tesxx);
    strcat(player, ot);
    strcat(player, testt);
    strcat(player, oty);
    //Move the cursor to row 15 and column 19 and then prints "Hello World!"
    //To move the cursor you have to print "\x1b[r;cH", where r and c are respectively
    //the row and column where you want your cursor to move
    //The top screen has 30 rows and 50 columns
    //The bottom screen has 30 rows and 40 columns
    printf(player);

    // Main loop
    while (aptMainLoop())
    {
        //Scan all the inputs. This should be done once for each frame
        hidScanInput();

        //hidKeysDown returns information about which buttons have been just pressed (and they weren't in the previous frame)
        u32 kDown = hidKeysDown();

        if (kDown & KEY_START) break; // break in order to return to hbmenu

        // Flush and swap framebuffers
        gfxFlushBuffers();
        gfxSwapBuffers();

        //Wait for VBlank
        gspWaitForVBlank();
    }

    gfxExit();
    return 0;
}
```

why am I getting this error. I am working in C and I'm making a game for the 3ds and I want to be able to control the placement of my player char by using my int variables tesx and test. I don't understand why my offset is 0 and why its going off bounds.

````
C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/gaame/source/main.c:24:9: warning: 'strcat' offset 0 is out of the bounds [0, 0] [-Warray-bounds]
   24 |         strcat(player, testt);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/gaame/source/main.c:22:9: warning: '__builtin_stpcpy' offset 0 is out of the bounds [0, 0] [-Warray-bounds]
   22 |         strcat(player, tesxx);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~```
````

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Are you trying to compile that as C? (EDIT: Yes, you are. Replace your first include with `<iostream>` and rename your file `main.cpp` and try compiling again, with a C++ compiler.)

Comment: If you're working with C++, add a `#include <iostream>` and a missing closing brace `}`. See [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/qeD0LJuWI)

Comment: Try renaming your `main.c` file to `main.cpp`. Be sure to call the c++ compiler, and not the c Variation.

Comment: Add `#include <iostream>` and use `g++` rather than `gcc` to compile this.

Comment: `a='\\';` is  a problem too.

Answer (score 1):

The header `<string>` and the class `std::string` defined in that header are part of the C++ standard library. The .c suffix of the file main.c implies that it is written in the C language. It appears that you are attempting to use C++ features in the C language. This doesn't work because they are separate languages. You cannot use C++ features in C.